# Made for TV movie (I think) about a parapelegic man making a suit to walk

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I believe that this was a made for TV movie, probably from the late '70s or early '80s. One scene has been stuck in my mind since, for unknown reasons, it terrified me as a kid.

In this scene, the character is in some sort of trailer workshop. He's been working on a powered exoskeleton suit that will enable him to walk. It is not a metal bars/springs/motors exoskeleton as some of the real "power assist" exoskeletons being made today are. It's more like a NASA space suit in hard, red plastic. I don't recall if there was a helmet, but I'm pretty sure that it was a full upper body/arms suit. He opens the back door of the trailer (I believe it's a ramp door like you'd use on a vehicle trailer) and walks out.

That's really all I remember of the show. I recall watching it with my Dad, and we didn't go to a lot of movies, so I'm pretty certain it was made for TV. However, it could have been shown in theaters and this was a TV cut of it.

I remember *nothing* of the rest of the movie. I'm reasonably certain that the making of this suit was at least one of the major themes of the show, though I don't know if it was the *main* plot point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is *[Exo-Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exo-Man)* (1977).

The main character builds himself an exoskeleton and fights baddies in a red spacesuit affair.

[image]

Comment: For the record, this film is *terrible*. If you feel the urge to watch it, might I suggest you use the time to ring your mother. You don't do it often enough and it puts her in a good mood for days.

Comment: Good answer. It's probably a better fit than my suggestion.

Comment: This has to be it. My memory was a little off on what the suit looked like, and for some reason, the camera angle in my head makes me think this frame was rotated 180° - I distinctly remember "seeing" it from the other side, but, well my memory was wrong on other things, too. Seriously, how did you come up with this so fast?

Comment: @FreeMan - It was my top result for 'paraplegic exoskeleton 1970s movie' on google. I saw this years ago and couldn't remember the name, but it took longer to write up the answer than to find it.

Comment: I suppose I could have searched myself, but then... No magic internet pointz for doing my own work. :)

Comment: I think someone used clips from this in a fake "what if MCU Avengers was a 70s television show" Youtube vid. The idea being that *that* exoskeleton was Bad 70s TV Iron Man!

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern - The 70s and 80s were a crazy time; https://images.says.com/uploads/story_source/source_image/7942/03af.jpeg

Comment: He's still a cool-looking Cap in that pic!

Answer (score 2):

This was a series, I believe, titled [*M.A.N.T.I.S.*](https://www.tvguide.com/tvshows/mantis/1000236834/) (1994-1997?), though the pilot was movie-length.  It was set in Vancouver, BC (Canada).  The protagonist was played by Carl Lumbly; he was paraplegic due to an accident, and created the suit to let him walk -- but found that it also let him do things that made him into a superhero.

As I recall, it only ran one (or a partial) season; while it had good production values, it was a 1990s TV series, in a genre that required special effects; overall quality was similar to the Bill Bixby *The Incredible Hulk* in terms of the hero's action sequences.

Comment: MANTIS was my first guess, but the timescales are wrong and the suit was actually not crappy.

Comment: Definitely far too new. Heck, I was out of college by the time this hit the air.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an episode from the British TV series The New Avengers, episode [The Last Of The Cybernauts?](http://theavengers.tv/forever/newave-3.htm).

> One trip too many to the well? Pursued by our threesome, double-agent Kane meets a fiery death in a car crash—or does he? Horribly deformed and confined to a wheelchair, Kane learns of the secret of the cybernauts and devises a means to inhabit a robot body in order to exact his revenge on the Avengers!

Here's the guy in his robot suit.

Comment: The description broadly fits, but the 'cybernaut' is a metal-faced monster

Comment: In their first two appearances, yes. But this episode the baddie uses the  technology to become part man part machine.  Although I think Exo-Man is probably the right answer. TLOTC? doesn't feature him opening a trailer door.